# Upload larger files to S3 using not multipart but put upload

Tags: file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload and encode video file using S3, elastic-transcoder and lambda fuction.

Lambda function and settings work fine, but when I upload video file(mp4), it is automatically 'multipart' uploaded (because it's larger than 5mb).
And maybe because of that, job processes on elastic-transcoder run three times. So I got to run unnecessary job twice on each upload (the first job successfully encode video file).

Is there any ways to avoid this, such as force to upload larger file (about 60mb) not using 'multipart' but 'put' function? And I'd prefer to do this job from browser console for non engineers.

And this is lambda function to submit job for ElasticTranscoder. When I upload video files, 'put' doesn't work but 'multipart' event works. 'Put' event works for smaller files like images or txt, just for testing.

```
console.log('Loading event');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
var ets = new aws.ElasticTranscoder({apiVersion: '2012-09-25', region: 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   console.log('Received event:');
   console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, '  '));
   var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
   var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
   var fileName = key.split('.')[0];
   s3.getObject({Bucket:bucket, Key:key},
      function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
           console.log('error getting object ' + key + ' from bucket ' + bucket +
           '. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.');
       context.done('error','error getting file'+err);
    } else {
        console.log("### JOB KEY ### " + key);
        ets.createJob({
            PipelineId: '***',
            Input: {
                Key: key,
                FrameRate: 'auto',
                Resolution: 'auto',
                AspectRatio: 'auto',
                Interlaced: 'auto',
                Container: 'auto',
            },
            Output: {
                Key: fileName + '.m3u8',
                ThumbnailPattern: fileName + '-thumbs-{count}',
                PresetId: '1351620000001-200035',
                Rotate: 'auto'
            }
        }, function(error, data) {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Job submitted');
            }
        });
    }
  }
);
```

};

Comment: *"maybe because of that"* Maybe... but you should investigate that more thoroughly.  Enable logging on the bucket and see how many events are actually happening.  How are you uploading, now? With the console?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot. I'm uploading now from console and running lambda to encode video files.